# Pivot table: distinct count

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I would like to get distinct count of a column in a pivot table in Excel. To do this I have to select the "Add this data to the Data Model" option in the screenshot below, which has been greyed out. What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: That can happen if your workbook is in compatibility mode

Comment: Why is the field "Table/Range" free?